# firebase currently signed-in user is returning null

Tags: angular, firebase

As per google docs, I've tried the below method to retrieve the current user details, but i'm getting null response from firebase v9.

Below is my code

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
const app = initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(app);
const dbRef = ref(getDatabase(app));
const auth = getAuth();

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    console.log(user);
    const uid = user.uid;
    console.log(uid);
  }
});
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    console.log(user);
    const uid = user.uid;
    console.log(uid);
  }
});
```

}

I'm using `ngx-auth-firebaseui` for authentication for login in my angular app.

Its not happening after login, When I directly visits the profile page, I'm getting null for currentuser,

[image]

Comment: Please paste the full code and add more context. Are you still getting a null user immediately after signing in? Add the link to the docs where you got the code from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solutions, this might help others

I've imported `AuthProcessService` from `ngx-auth-firebaseui`

```
this.auth.user$.subscribe(res => {
  if(res) {
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```

Now I can get the current logged in user

Comment: Great. Thanks for posting back the answer. Do accept it as correct later on